# Ember transitionTo action in parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Say I am in an `<iframe>` in my Ember app.

Is it possible to have the result of a transition opened in the parent/main window?

```
this.transitionTo('someRoute') //Or link-to someRoute
```

i.e. Currently I am in an `<iframe>` context, but I want the result of this transition to happen in the main browser window. Is that possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand what do you need, but take a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748837/invoke-ember-action-from-plain-javascript-in-iframe/). As for me, it's kinda similar problem.

Comment: Actually I kind of want the reverse. i.e. From an iframe context, I want some transition to new route take place & I want this to happen in the main window's context. So you can say that I want the iframe to be no longer available/destroyed from this action.